# Jquery remove dynamic element before current element

Tags: jquery, html

So I'm building this quiz, and I'm adding extra questions and answers with jQuery. Now I also want to remove the questions and answers.

HTML:

```
<div id="tab1" class="questionsList">
    <br/>
    <button type="button" onclick="addAwnser(1)">Add Awnser</button>
    <br/>
    <br/>
    Question: <input type="text" placeholder="What's your question?" name="question[]"/><br/><br/>
    <div class="awnsersList">
          <input type="text" class="question" name="awnser[1][]" placeholder="awnser"/>
          <input type="checkbox" name="correct_awnser[1][]" value="1"/>
<form method="post" action="">
<div class="col-md-12">
    <div class="well">
        <div class="input-group">
            <input type="text" name="quizName" class="form-control" placeholder="Quiz name" aria-describedby="basic-addon1">
        </div>
        <hr/>
        <button id="add-tab" type="button"> Add Question</button>
        <div id="tabs">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#tab1" class="ActiveQuestion">1</a></li>
            </ul>
            <div id="tab1" class="questionsList">
                <br/>
                <button type="button" onclick="addAwnser(1)">Add Awnser</button>
                <br/>
                <br/>
                Question: <input type="text" placeholder="What's your question?" name="question[]"/><br/><br/>
                <div class="awnsersList">
                    <input type="text" class="question" name="awnser[1][]" placeholder="awnser"/>
                    <input type="checkbox" name="correct_awnser[1][]" value="1"/>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <button value="Save quiz" type="submit">Submit</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    window.awnserCount = 2;
    window.count = 0;
    $("div#tabs").tabs();
    $("button#add-tab").click(function() {
        $("div#tabs").tabs("refresh");

        var num_tabs = $("div#tabs ul li").length + 1;

        $("div#tabs ul").append("<li><a href='#tab" + num_tabs + "'>" + num_tabs + "</a></li>");
        $("div#tabs").append("<div id='tab"+num_tabs+"' class='questionsList'>"+
        "<br/><button type='button' onclick='addAwnser("+num_tabs+")'>Add Awnser</button><br/><br/>"+
        "Question: <input type='text' placeholder='Whats your question?' name='question[]'/><br/><br/>"+
        "<div class='awnsersList'>"+
        "<input type='text' class='question' name='awnser["+num_tabs+"][]' placeholder='1st awnser'/>"+
        "<input type='checkbox' name='correct_awnser[1][]' value='1'/><br/>"+
        "</div>"+
        "<button onclick='removeQuestion(" + num_tabs + ")' type='button'>Remove this question</button>"+
        "</div>");

        $("div#tabs").tabs("refresh");
    });
});


function removeQuestion(questionId){
    removeCurrent(questionId);

    checkNumbers(questionId);
}

function removeCurrent(questionId) {
    $("#tabs li a").each(function (){
        if ($(this).html() == questionId) {
            $(this).remove().hide().css("display", "none");
            $("div#tabs").tabs("refresh");
            window.count ++;
        }
        $("#tab" + questionId).remove().css("display", "none");
        $("div#tabs").tabs("refresh");
    });
    $("div#tabs").tabs("refresh");
}

function checkNumbers(number){
    $( "#tabs li a" ).each(function() {
        var curreId = $(this).attr("id").split('id-');
        if(curreId[1] > number){
            $(this).html((curreId[1] - 1));
        }
    });
    $("div#tabs").tabs("refresh");
}

function countCurrentAwnsers(QuestionId){
    inputs = 0;
    window.inputs = 0;
    var inputs =  $("div#tab"+QuestionId +" .awnsersList").find($("input[type='checkbox']"));
    console.log(inputs.length + 1);

    window.inputs = inputs;

}

function addAwnser(QuestionId){
    var inputs =  $("div#tab"+QuestionId +" .awnsersList").find($("input[type='checkbox']"));

    console.log("clicked" + QuestionId);

    var AnswerId = QuestionId+"_"+parseInt(inputs.length + 1);
    console.log(AnswerId);

    $("div#tab"+QuestionId +" .awnsersList").append("<div id='"+QuestionId+"_"+parseInt(inputs.length + 1)+"' <br/><input type='text' class='question' name='awnser["+QuestionId+"][]' placeholder='awnser'/>"+
    "<input type='checkbox' name='correct_awnser["+QuestionId+"][]' value='"+parseInt(inputs.length + 1)+"'/><button type='button' class='RemoveAwnser' >Remove awnser</button> <br/><br/></div>");
    window.awnserCount ++;
}


$('.RemoveAwnser').click(function() {
    $(this).prev().prev().remove();
    $(this).prev().remove();
    $(this).remove();
});
```

What I'm trying to achieve is that the remove awnser button will remove the 2 inputs infront of it along with itself. I'm not getting any errors so I have absolutely no idea what I'm doing wrong.

Note that you will only get a remove awnser button on dynamic created content because a question with no possible awnsers is not much of a question.

I'm sure most of my code is actually very crappy but cannot be changed due to PHP thats putting it all in my database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might want to try this out.

```
$(this).closest().find(":checkbox").remove();
$(this).closest().find("input[type=text]").remove();
```

Assuming you want to remove the last posted answer.

It would have been better if you would have posted your current working code

**EDIT**

Since you mentioned that contents are dynamically being generated. Whenever you want to attach eny events for dynamically generated elements always use the `on()` function.

Try this:**[Assuming the traversal order inside the function is correct]**

```
$('.RemoveAwnser').on('click',function() {
    $(this).prev().prev().remove();
    $(this).prev().remove();
    $(this).remove();
});
```

Comment: This is not doing anything for me. I was thinking I could generate a div around each group of inputs and remove the parent.

Comment: As I told you, it would be easier if you could post your code

Comment: I have put all my code in there right now. Sorry if it's not easy to read, i'm still learning how to style my code on this site properly.

Comment: Where is remove answer button in your html? Is it generated for every single question?

Comment: It's only generated for all the dynamic content.

Comment: This worked, I found another code that works just the same, but found it's (better) for dynamic content. Not exactly sure if true but It's the following:

     $(document).on('click','.RemoveAwnser',function() {
        $(this).prev().prev().remove();
        $(this).prev().remove();
        $(this).remove();
    });

Comment: You are attaching the event to the entire document, I dont think thats good, its better to be more specific when you are trying to attach event to the elements

Comment: And do not forget to accept the answer if this solved your issue :)